# Using a Python interpreter to create a program that can evolve

Tags: python, dynamic, interpreter

my goal is simple, yet extremely complicated because of its simplicity. Making a program that can optimize itself. For now I will make a simple program to research the possibilities of it. Unfortunately i am new to interpreters, and python. Therefore I would like to ask for guidance. Here is my first program's steps.

> Python Interpreter program loads code from a file(ex. Test0) and runs.
>
> Test0 code says to print 'Hello'.
>
> 'Hello' is printed.
>
> Test0 code stops.
>
> Python Interpreter takes the printed word and scrambles it.
>
> Python interpreter then edits the code from Test0 to print the
>   scrambled word.
>
> The next time Test0 is run it prints the scrambled word.

Comment: Try using the execfile() command to modify a config file. That way you keep your code and your optimization separate.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

you can do something like:

config = {}
execfile("something.py",config)

config will contain a dictionary of the global variables after executing the file, and you can then write back to something.py. This is, however, not recommended for any sort of production code.

Comment: Well eventually I will be working with more than just variables, but entire lines of code. Therefore as practice I wanted to do something simple like a variable change rather than a code change, but using the same method as the code change would need.

Comment: Execfile will execute the python in the config file. You can then use the parent program to calculate the new output, and write back to the config file. You might want to do some research on self modifying code as well...its very error prone, and a more favored approach is machine learning, where you designate a target behavior, measure the distance between that target and your actual code behavior, and then modify the behavior of the program based on this metric.

Comment: As an alternate case, you CAN do f=open(\_\_file\_\_,'a') and append code to the file you are currently executing with f.write('code here') which will be a VERY error prone, but will work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could store the "Test0" output to a file (result.txt), and use another script to edit "Test0", running "Test1" to edit "Test0" and replace the "hello" for the output (that will be saved in result.txt)

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm) is the tutorial about file manipulation in Python. You can use this to edit not only strings, but the code itself, adding, editing and removing operators for example.